# unicode object is not callable when opening a json file

Tags: python, json, unicode

Why this code :

```
input_file  = file( os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), "res/channels.json"))                
j = json.loads(input_file.read())
```

genrate this error :

```
 input_file  = file( os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), "res/channels.json"))                
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

I just would like to understand this kind of problems once and for all.

Comment: Did you assign something to `file` somewhere else in your code? What does `repr(file)` print?

Comment: And why not to use `open()` instead?

Comment: @twil: `open()` and `file()` are the same thing, but yes, using `open()` is encouraged over using `file()`.

Comment: Also, why call `.read()` when you can let `json.load(input_file)` (no `s` at the end of `load`) do the reading for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: exactly. although I know about `file()` and `open()` it takes me some time to figure out what it is. And often I see code like `file = open()` which adds to not using `file()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options why the error you see is raised:

1. You bound `os.path.abspath` to a unicode value
2. You bound `os.path.join` to a unicode value
3. You bound `file` to a unicode value

Of the three, the last one is the most likely.

Either don't assign to `file` elsewhere in your code, or *delete* the `file` global masking the built-in with:

```
del file
```

Python documentation [recommends](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) that you use the [`open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) instead. I'd also use [`json.load()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) (no `s`) to load the file contents directly, as well as a `with` statement to ensure that the file object is closed automatically:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), "res/channels.json")) as input_file:
    j = json.load(input_file)
```